# standard java type for oracle type FLOAT is BigDecimal in classes12.jar but double in ojdbc14.jar

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am storing one value by executing one procedure. For that procedure am setting out parameter type as FLOAT.If classes12.jar is used as jdbc driver,the result from procedure data type is coming BigDecimal in java class(java 1.6) ,but getting Double type when ojdbc14/ojdbc6.jar.

Comment: Well, `classes12.jar` was meant for Java 1.2, so it doesn't really matter anymore. Unless you're foolish enough to still use an outdated library.

Comment: I wasn't there, but I'm pretty sure it wasn't an accident. Why do you care? Just use a recent library and work with that. Documentation is available on Oracle's pages, but I can't imagine you'll find any useful information about a change that happened 20 years ago.

Comment: Do you have clients that need a reason beyond "this code has been released 18 years ago, and has been obsolete for the last sixteen years"?

Comment: Judging from the specification I'd say it's a bug in `classes12.jar` since `FLOAT` should have been mapped to `Double` since at least JDBC version 1.2.